# Is there a Chrome embedded in Visual Studio Code

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, v8

> Version: 1.49.0 (system setup)
> Commit: e790b931385d72cf5669fcefc51cdf65990efa5d
> Date: 2020-09-10T13:22:08.892Z
> Electron: 9.2.1
> Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
> Node.js: 12.14.1
> V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763

There is a **Chrome version** in   Visual studio code (**Help -> About**).what does it mean ?
Is there a embedded chrome in VScode or V8 needs chrome to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code is one of many applications built on the Chromium platform, via the "Electron" framework. See e.g. https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/04/microsofts-new-code-editor-is-built-on-googles-chromium/.

Another IDE built on Electron/Chromium is GitHub's [Atom](https://atom.io/).

For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework); and for a similar project: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework.